# Help Identifying LEGO With A Pink 3(｀(00) ´ )Ɛ Face

Tags: set-identification

I cannot add a picture, but they are green, brown, and pink pieces. One of the pink has what looks like a pig's face.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

- Other sets with *Minecraft Piggy Face Piece* ***[Here](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=19727pb005&in=S)***.